# fiddler shows 200/OK response but jquery receives error in asp.net web api cors

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, cors

I was trying to implement CORS by following the [post here](http://bit.ly/XhVsog).

It's just that when I execute a jquery call it is receiving error. The response text is '' with status text as 'error'.

But, looking into Fiddler the response is 200/OK with the correct json-formatted result.

here's my jquery call:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:9999/api/v1/xxxxxxxx/", function (allData) {
                log.debug(allData);
            }).success(function (allData) {
            }).error(function (xhr, status, data) {
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log(data);
                console.log(status);
            });
```

here's the screenshot of the response:

1] [Firebug](https://skydrive.live.com/#cid=ECBDDB2A827CAFC4&id=ECBDDB2A827CAFC4!1046)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

A 200 OK response still might mean a CORS failure. The response needs to have the right response headers to allow the Ajax call.

From your screen shot your Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header is wrong -- it should just be `*` but your has `*, *` for some reason.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed it also. If I explicitly defined my website origin in webapconfig, ex. config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("xttp://localhost:53591","*","*")); , Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header shows " xttp://localhost:53591, *"